# broken link in APG's man page

Tags: man

How can I create an issue for the broken link in APG's man page?

[image: apg man page project home page link broken]

My try: I tried sending an email to the address above the broken link, but it seems that it's no longer accessible.

[image: email not delivered]

The highlighted text reads:

> It seems that the email address to which you have sent your email is inaccessible.

what can i do to notify the package maintainer?

[image]
screenshot of apg's man page

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a broken web site, and has nothing to do with unix or linux.

Comment: it's about correcting wrong info in the man page of a linux package

Comment: The accuracy and/or working status of some random web site has nothing to with **this** site.

Comment: I've talking about the bug in the "BUG" in apg's man page.

Comment: "One of my acquaintances said something wrong about some obscure tool that happens to run on linux, but his phone is broken and I don't know his email address or where he is. How can I contact him to tell him he's wrong?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of the concept of "[man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)".

[What you're looking at](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/apgbfm.1.html) isn't not the man page of `apg`. Man pages are installed in system, and are invoked with the command `man`. So to read man page of `apg` you give command `man apg`.

Major distros host online repositories of man pages online. This is Canonical's repository, hosted in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository). As advised in the repository front page and the bottom of the pages themselves, issues with the site are also to be reported via Ubuntu's [Launchpad bug reporting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+filebug).

The reason those links are dead is that

> Sadly, in 2017, the project went offline, and stopped responding to
> email, and was removed from most package managers

[Source](https://github.com/jabenninghoff/apg)

So while Mirzazhnov is original creator of `apg`, he has abandoned it; hence the links on the site aren't valid anymore. It's been picked up by other contributors of OpenSource community. Some maintain it for a single distribution, several forks can be found in GitHub etc. This is neiter the first nor the last OS project to meet such a fate. How much development has been done since is unclear, for example Benninghoff's (the maintainer of the sourced GitHub page) latest release dates Oct 13 2019.

If you believe you encountered a bug with Ubuntu's `apg` itself, or the actual man page available with `man apg`, you need to report it as instructed in [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en).

I just checked `man apg` on Debian, and the same broken links are there. With Debian a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877601) has been done, but with a quick search I didn't find one for [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Comment: FWIW, using The Wayback Machine, the page archive is readable until the 2013 version of the site: https://web.archive.org/web/20130310084317/http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/ (where things stop at 2003 as written in the *package* description).